# behaviour of \paragraphfootnotes in memoir.cls

Tags: footnotes, memoir, para

The switch `\paragraphfootnotes` in memoir has one odd, at least unusual feature: whenever a footnote starts a new line, it is indented. The idea of the para-feature is to have one paragraph with all the footnotes of a page. Is it possible to turn this off?

Is is possible to allow paragraph-footnotes to run onto the next page?

This is a minimal example. Footnote 10 is within the block and indented. There are surely scenarios where this is what you want, but normally not.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\paragraphfootnotes
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}  
\lipsum[1]\footnote{} test\footnote{test test test testtesttesttest test testtest}
test\footnote{test test test testtesttesttest test testtest}test\footnote{test test test
  testtesttesttest test testtest} test\footnote{test test test testtesttesttest test
  testtest}test\footnote{test test test testtesttesttest test testtest} test\footnote{test
}test\footnote{test}test\footnote{test }test\footnote{test}test\footnote{test
}test\footnote{test}test\footnote{test }test\footnote{test}test\footnote{test }test\footnote{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please provide a minimal example of what ever you are asking about. That makes it a lot easier for others to understand your problem and perhaps answer your question.